# performance difference generator and looping

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

I've been working with generators more recently and have a question around performance of generators and looping. From my research and what I understand about generators, they are appropriate when you don't want to store the whole "list" you are iterating over in memory then loop over it. Instead generators return the item in each list at the time of call and keep track of where to pick up next time the call is made. Do I have that correct?

While it seems very similar to a for loop, I unsure of a performance difference ignoring memory saving advantages.

For example, a scenario where:

CASE A:

```
def my_generator():
   for api_resp in paginator.make_api_call()
   # where api_resp has the format: {"Contents": [{"Key": "value1", "last_mod_dt": datetime}, {"Key": "value2", "last_mod_dt": datetime}]} and can have thousands/millions of entries in the list.
       for item in api_resp["Contents"]:
           yield item["Key"]

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for item in my_generator():
        item["sub_string_of_item"].append("item")
```

CASE B:

```
def my_generator():
   for api_resp in paginator.make_api_call()
   # where api_resp has the format: {"Contents": [{"Key": "value1", "last_mod_dt": datetime}, {"Key": "value2", "last_mod_dt": datetime}]} and can have thousands/millions of entries in the list.
       yield api_resp["Contents"]

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for item in my_generator():
        for obj in item:
            item[parse_substring_of(obj["Key"]].append(obj["Key"])
```

Which one is more performant? Does this change as the number of items increase? I can do it either way, I'm just trying to understand the most efficient way to use the generator.

Thanks for any help! Any links to relevant articles are appreciated for further research!

EDIT: added for clarification of multiple API calls being part of the generator function

Comment: Why do you create `my_dict` and not use it?

Comment: Have you tried measuring the performance of either implementation, e.g. by using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html)? Also, in case B, it seems rather silly to pay for the construction of a generator if you are only going to produce one element.

Comment: "**when you don't want to store the whole "list" you are iterating over in memory**".  If the thing you are iterating over is indeed a `list`, then it necessarily is wholly stored in memory anyways, regardless of how you access its elements

Comment: thanks for the comments. @hpaulj this was just an example, I do use it later. the example was truncated to show the relevant portion of the code

Comment: the api resp has the format above, and what I need to iterate over is the list of dicts (the value of "Contents")

Comment: Case B only yields one thing, and quits.  That's not much of a generator.  You might as well do `for obj in make_api_call()['Contents']; my_dict[...] = obj["Key"]`.  Generations help with memory and performance you can string several together.  Just calling one generator (layer) doesn't do anything for you.

Comment: good point, I didn't think of that. What you outlined is essentially Case A correct?

Comment: If you just need to iterate on a list, inserting a generator layer doesn't improve performance.